# Wakanda event code destination folder not "model"

Tags: wakanda

When i want to create the `onGet` event code for a calculated attribute the proposed destination folder is "`methods`" where it should be "`model`" as described in the [on-line documentation](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.de.html#/Wakanda/0.v10/Create-a-calculated-attribute.300-1138562.en.html);

Strange enough, both files "`<..>.events.js`"  and "`<..>.methods.js`" already exist under the `model/<..>` folders (where `<..>` stands for each datastore class in my model) but seem to be ignored by Wakanda Studio.

I did not find where i could change that destination.

Is it possible and where?

Answer (score 0):

`<..>-events.js` and `<..>-methods.js` are recognized by model only when they are included in `model.js`, which can be found next to model.

Do you see code like this in `model.js`?

```
include("./methods/<..>/<..>-events.js");
include("./methods/<..>/<..>-methods.js");
```

Comment: No, i just see the following lines:  // converted from guided model

include("./Model/Moulin/Moulin-events.js");
include("./Model/Moulin/Moulin-methods.js");

include("./Model/Riviere/Riviere-events.js");
include("./Model/Riviere/Riviere-methods.js");

Comment: but when i add event code i get the line  "include("./methods/Moulin/Moulin-events.js");" in the Model.js file, and a folder "Moulin" is added under methods, with the file Moulin-events.js in it. I expected the attribute-related event code to be created in the existing js files (under Model/<..>)